# jni.h file not found

Tags: r, macos, rjdbc

I'm ultimately trying to install the RJDBC package on a mac running R 3.3.3 and Java 12 and Mojave OS.

When trying to install RDJBC I get the following error:

```
configure: error: One or more Java configuration variables are not set.
Make sure R is configured with full Java support (including JDK). Run
R CMD javareconf
as root to add Java support to R.

If you don't have root privileges, run
R CMD javareconf -e
to set all Java-related variables and then install rJava.
```

So then I go ahead and run R CMD javareconf in the terminal and I get the following error:

```
conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
```

I've found various questions online around the same topic and have tried out suggested solutions and none have worked for me.  Ity could be a combination of my OS/Java version.  Would someone be willing to walk me through a fix here?

**Update:**

Stacktrace

```
WARNING: Initial Java 12 release has broken JNI support and does NOT work. Use stable Java 11 (or watch for 12u if avaiable).
ERROR: Java exception occurred during rJava bootstrap - see stderr for Java stack trace.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.verifyMemberAccess(Reflection.java:130)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowVerifyAccess(AccessibleObject.java:673)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.verifyAccess(AccessibleObject.java:666)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:638)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkAccess(Field.java:1075)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:416)
Error in .jcheck(silent = FALSE) : 
  java.lang.NullPointerException.jcall(f, "Ljava/lang/Object;", "get", .jcast(ic, "java/lang/Object"))new("jobjRef", jobj = <pointer: 0x7fd4a04ac4b8>, jclass = "java/lang/NullPointerException")
```

Interestingly, it seems to work when I run R through terminal, but not in Rstudio.

Answer (score 2):

This will need some tweaking. In general, R, Java and rJava are not quite easy things to setup when they are supposed to work together. Make sure to go through: http://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/

Note that due to changes in Java 12 it is no longer possible to dynamically affect location of shared libraries via reflection - this affects `rJava`. I am pretty sure you won't get `rJava` and any other `JNI` based codes working properly with Java 12 in R.

Once you have your R configured, it will work as expected

```
> R

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

...
...

> install.packages("RJDBC")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
...

> library(RJDBC)
Loading required package: DBI
>
```

**Update**

For `Java 12` try following. Inside `~/.profile` add following line

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 12)
```

then, run

```
> sudo R CMD javareconf \
JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME} \
JAVA=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java \
JAVAC=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac \
JAVAH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javah \
JAR=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jar
```

and, inside `R`

```
> system("java -version")
java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
> library(RJDBC)
Loading required package: DBI
Loading required package: rJava
>
```

Of course, you still need `XCode.app` as it contains headers for `JNI`.

**Update**

In order to make sure all the apps are getting `Java 11` instead of `Java 12` (not only CLI based) you can "disable" `Java 12` following way.

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents
sudo mv Info.plist Info.plist~
```

Since now, even though you haven't removed `Java 12`, `RStudio` will pick up correct version.

[image]

Comment: So I'll need to downgrade to java 11?

Comment: What is the best way to switch from java 12 to 11.  I have 11 installed, but 12 is being used.

Comment: This didn't work as expected, installing RJDBC did end up working but getting a Java Exception when trying to use it.

Comment: what would you suggest?

Comment: You have to post the exception and stack trace. Without it, it’s like walking through a fog.

Comment: added to question

Comment: I think you will have to work with Java 11 :( Some old, JNI based, codes use reflection trick to point to shared libs. It doesn’t work with Java 12

Comment: for some reason, I was able to get R in my terminal to work, but for some reason Rstudio is still using java 12.  How do I switch which version of Java Rstudio is using?

Comment: I don’t recall now, but for sure there is a place where you can set jvm version. if i find i i will post it here