# R session aborting when library(xlsx) MacOS

Tags: java, r, xlsx

I have a MacBook Air M1 2020 running on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1. and I use RStudio 2023.12.0+369 and R 4.3.2.

I would like to use the `xlsx` library but each time I use `library(xlsx)` the R session aborts itself.

I looked on internet, some people say to use the command `sudo R CMD javareconf` in the terminal but when I do it I have the error:

> conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
> #include <jni.h>
> ^~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
> Unable to compile a JNI program

Most of the solutions I found on internet are either for Windows, or use the above but solution, which doesn't work for me.

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118245/jni-h-file-not-found) which seems related. Alternatively might be worth giving [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html) a shot.

Comment: or [`openxlsx2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx2/index.html)

Comment: Only diff to your set-up: R 4.3.1. `library(xlsx)` issues *Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(jli, FALSE)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib':
  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib'*

Comment: (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Internet Plug-*Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' **(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))*** As r2evans and jay.sf already suggested, you are better off by using an alternative.

Comment: From the terminal where you run "R CMD javareconf", what is the output of command "java -version"?

Comment: Also, what is the output of command "/usr/libexec/java_home -V"?